# Too much combination to expand a macro

Tags: c++, boost, c-preprocessor

I want to apply a function to data buffers and their types are known at runtime.
I use for that a templated function `template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3> void myFunction()`.

`myFunction` is a member of a class, which also contains the data structures storing the buffers. The buffers are stored in a char* pointer, and I have an enumerate to know the actual data type of my buffer, allowing me to cast the pointer into the correct type.
I also have a data structure to register all of the data type combination in that way :

```
// functionPtr is declared earlier
functionPtr = static_cast<void(*)(void)>( &myFunction< DataType1, DataType2, DataType3 >);
registerFunction(functionPtr);
```

Finally, I wrote a macro to parse each type combination.

My problem is that it seems to be too much data to expand for the compiler. I reduced to the minimal example below :

## [Preproc](https://gitlab.com/PavelBraginskiy/preproc), 915 bytes

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

// List the possible types
#define STRIP_ALL_TYPES         \
    (eIBT_Int8)(eIBT_UInt8)     \
    (eIBT_Int16)(eIBT_UInt16)   \
    (eIBT_Int32)(eIBT_UInt32)   \
    (eIBT_Real32)               \
    (eIBT_Binary)               \
    (eIBT_Label16)(eIBT_Label32)

# Generate all the combinations
#define GENERATE_TYPE_COMBINATION(r, product) (product)

// Generate the instruction for a given type combination
#define TEMPLATE_SPECIFIC_TYPE_COMBINATION(r, data, elem)\
functionPtr = static_cast<void(*)(void)>(\
                &CurProcessorType::myFunction< BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(elem) >);

// Generate all the possible instructions
#define GENERATE_TEMPLATE(ST)\
BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(TEMPLATE_SPECIFIC_TYPE_COMBINATION, _, \
                      BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_PRODUCT(GENERATE_TYPE_COMBINATION, ST))

GENERATE_TEMPLATE((STRIP_ALL_TYPES)(STRIP_ALL_TYPES)(STRIP_ALL_TYPES))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVNha9swEP3uX3EQGNIwDd1gjDYNJJ7SGZxYtZUPg4JQbKUVOLKRlEJ@farYTeY22Xof7Dvp8d7dk9QY2Zi62O8HShfVtpQwWtW1dcOm25DW1ubquWnGQTAcQqKsA/csoamtVatKgts10gaDUq6VlpCzLKZ8kiSc/aEkh2M8BocvkvGU8Vi7n7hLl21@CXH9owfxxTni@7cewhcfEJkUVbfajz5iqrQwu/8hErGS1amTtvKUQTCAe6mlEU6CqKrWj6LerDyfU7X@68Y9WZBswkhrBo/S@TReTFicLpAJwbtbbguHAR2z1uET84FVaeuM3/KssK4NCHhSL1K3pvclT4qMzGlyUMwpieJZHF2ULoUTIchKbvBjsN7qVoA6A3dgnScseCGsG73UqkRfMTr88Rh1zvTjS7Q19HhJmO/p5mazm73xjWCapjnjlPKcPHCyWM5RKwljfPt@1KOJp0vVm/uSm29Dopz5/t@pzNKMk0n0G31uRAg8hPOZurhIymmW/lpGDP3zXEP/ALA/x/NW0YeXgT9fwPv9Kw)

By expanding the macro, the generated lines compiled by the compiler should look like :

```
functionPtr = static_cast<void(*)(void)>( &CurProcessorType::myFunction< eIBT_Label16, eIBT_Label16, eIBT_Label16 >);
```

but when I test my code on TIO, I get the error `.code.tio:23:1: error: macro "BOOST_PP_IIF_1" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given GENERATE_TEMPLATE((STRIP_ALL_TYPES)(STRIP_ALL_TYPES)(STRIP_ALL_TYPES))`

It works only with a few items in `STRIP_ALL_TYPES`.

Is there a workaround I can use to be able to compile?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to generate 1000 template specializations?  Also `static_cast<void(*)(void)>` is an illegal csst if myfunction is  non static.

Comment: Yes, I need 1000 specializations. Thanks for the tip about the `void(*)(void)`. I wanted to start as simple as possible but I also modified the prototype and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you were trying to achieve with `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH`, as `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_PRODUCT` already gives you all permutations of the template arguments:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

// List the possible types
#define STRIP_ALL_TYPES         \
    (eIBT_Int8)(eIBT_UInt8)     \
    (eIBT_Int16)(eIBT_UInt16)   \
    (eIBT_Int32)(eIBT_UInt32)   \
    (eIBT_Real32)               \
    (eIBT_Binary)               \
    (eIBT_Label16)(eIBT_Label32)

// Generate all the combinations
#define GENERATE_TYPE_COMBINATION(r, product)\
    functionPtr = static_cast<void(*)(void)>(\
                  &CurProcessorType::myFunction< BOOST_PP_SEQ_ENUM(product) >);

#define GENERATE_TEMPLATE(ST)\
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_PRODUCT(GENERATE_TYPE_COMBINATION, ST)

GENERATE_TEMPLATE((STRIP_ALL_TYPES)(STRIP_ALL_TYPES)(STRIP_ALL_TYPES))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJtS8MwEP7eXxEYSCrDoYLInIO2ZrPQtbHNPghC6EvGCl1TklTYr69Zu2n3ot6H5O7y5LnLk6sEqwRPm2aQl2lRZwxMEs6lGlXdAZOSi5t1VU0NYzQCXi4VUGsGKi5lnhQMqG3FpDHI2CovGYhI6GJqeR4l7xhF4GAfxm6FzLUJdUv1aHbusvUvIW4fehAdnCPu73oIHZwgQhYXXbZvfYSdl7HY/oXw4oQV3520kaZshZizkolYMRAXRStIyjeJJlQ5L3/kmCMfhRZBrRrUCRa261vEDXwohkDLm9WpMruKq7pMd5exEuAZSKWZUprGUk0@eZ7BaxPudnMKO/ixXTm1wIffIvpHxuPNdrZnnAA7CCJCMaYReqPIXy7goTaYmk/GhXbRAnvagRHZt3dEMQtCiiznleIweFk6BP76zqGeCC3YOTE8mRTz/4RpNM0X)

Also, I should note that the cast to `void(*)(void)` is not valid if `CurProcessorType::myFunction` is a non-static member function. You should use a member function pointer type.

Comment: I actually need to process each item of `product` to add a prefix, that's why I need to use `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH`. You helped me to rewrite the macros differently and it appears to work now. Thank you for your help. I also changed the function signature. I wanted to start as simpe as possible.